# sas displays flag variables with - sign

Tags: sql, sas, proc, proc-sql

I want to create table in SAS EG which will contain flag variables (for example if client has opened current account). This flag variables is stored in dwh table and has a value 1/0. But when I want to create table in SAS from this database I get -1 instead of 1. Is there any option how to avoid changing the flag value 1 to -1?

Comment: SAS shouldn't be changing the data from the data warehouse. Without code or a screenshot of your query a guess is all anyone can make. One possibility is a format applied to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're connecting to a SQL Server table with a binary field.  In SQL Server, binary variables have two values: -1 and 0.  You can't really fix it except by either changing the value or accepting that it will be a -1.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am connecting to a SQL Server. At least I know now, why -1 appears there, thanks.